Movie that has robots with 3 lasers in their heads
I watched this movie a long, long time ago. The only thing I can remember about it is - it had robots with lasers on their heads. I am assuming the robots were either bi-pedal or tri-pedal. There were 3 red lasers embedded in their heads, like a triangle and there is a scene where one of them burns a hole in a metal door using these lasers. I am assuming the robots were evil. We see the door-burning scene from the perspective of the people inside the room, into which the robot is trying to break in. Also, the movie was in color and I assuming it was released in the 80s or 90s.

The robots sound like they may be from Space Truckers (1996), and in the first scene, one does indeed burn through a door with its tri beam head laser to attack troops. This is the best image I could find at the moment:





Yes. This is the one. Thanks a lot. The trailer has the door burning scene I was talking about.

No problem :) I love this movie
